# Relating multiple cases to a content note

Tags: contentdocumentlink

I am basically trying to relate a note record to multiple cases. I understand that when I am trying to create a note it basically creates ContentDocument, ContentNote, and ContentVersion. I am not sure what other records it would create but I am aware that when I create the above-said objects certainly.

So, to relate a case to multiple records you would need ContentDocumentLink but the problem is when I am trying to link multiple cases, it would populate only the LinkedEntitlyTypeId on the ContentDocumentLink record. So, how can I get the other case record Ids? How does this magic happen (LinkedEntitlyTypeId is only one field and it cannot possibly hold multiple cases/values)?

I think LinkedEntitlyTypeId is polymorphic but it can't possibly hold multiple values, does it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentDocumentLink` is a junction object, so you need to create one record for each note that you want to link.  See [ContentNote Objects documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm).

[image]